# PHP file_get_contents returns 404 Not Found - Ignore Errors

Tags: php

I have run into an odd issue I do not fully understand. My webserver via PHP calls a PHP api. The rest api will route the request to the appropriate function in the photos.php file based on verb. GET, PUT, and DELETE requests all work fine, however the below POST request returns a 404 Not found. The problem is it works just fine from the browser or when I call it from Postman. The file absolutely does exist and has appropriate access. I don't have this problem with other POST requests either.

After about 5 hours fighting with this and reading 100 sites/articles, I came across an obscure reference to the stream_context_create option of "ignore_errors" => true. The moment I added that line the 404 disappeared and I could reach the api endpoint.

I don't understand how that's possible. The file was either there or it wasn't so the 404 was a lie. I don't want to ignore errors to get this to work. Any idea what's going on here?

```
    $apiUrl = 'http://localhost/api/v1/user/john/photos';

    // Setup http request
    $options = ["http" =>
        ["method" => "POST",
            "header" => "Content-Type: application/json",
            "ignore_errors" => true,
            "content" => $data
            ]
        ];
    // Call API
    $apiResponse = file_get_contents($apiUrl, NULL, stream_context_create($options));
```

Here is the error I receive:

> ```
> <b>Warning</b>: 
> file_get_contents(http://localhost/api/v1/user/john/photos): failed to
> open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> ```

curl Info:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost/api/v1/user/john/photos
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 214
    [request_size] => 147
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.015
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 229
    [speed_download] => 15266
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 229
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.015
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [local_port] => 53224
)
Header Info: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 15:14:23 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.21
Content-Length: 229
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Are you positively sure the URL is valid and it's not your browser the one that's fixing it, e.g., adding a trailing slash or something?

Comment: What Version of PHP did you used on what system Windows/Linux?

Comment: this is really strange indeed, isn't the ignore_error flag used to not make the file_get_contents throw out warnings about the http call ? the warning was the 404 message ?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to look into the logs from the webserver of the API? Maybe they will give you some insights.

Comment: The URL is valid as it works fine when I send test requests using postman. I'm on windows with PHP v. 5.6.21. I updated the post with the actual warning I received. Yes I do have access to the logs and it shows the same error and not much else.

Comment: Is your PHP script able to reach `localhost`? If your script is not hosted on your local machine, `localhost` may mean something different to your script then it means to your browser.

Oh, and for HTTP APIs I'd rather use http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php. It has all that shiny stuff like authentication, redirect handling etc.

Comment: Yes everything is on localhost and can be reached. There are no remote calls occurring at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking the answer to why file_get_contents was throwing an error without ignore_errors set to true, then perhaps these instructions will get you closer to the answer.  Please note these instructions assume that the php error logs have not been reviewed or are not useful yet and hope to help overcome those issues.

1. To locate your php error log put this at the top of your script (just temporarily for one load of the page)

   **phpinfo(); die();**
2. Now, after that page loads and you see your php info, search for **error_log** and locate that directory on your host.
3. If that value is empty, you may have log_errors turned off or the errors are printing into your apache error log.  If that is the case, try to find the apache error log.
4. With the error log available to you, replace your *phpinfo(); die();*  with these two calls. Turning off ignore_errors and run the file again.

   **error_reporting(E_ALL);  ini_set("display_errors", 1);**
5. Using the error log, can you find notices/warnings/errors related to the file_get_contents call and post them here if they do not clear up the question?

** EDIT **

Okay, using curl, get the response and request headers in complete and updating your question with the output, please.

```
ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// ...

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Then, after your curl_exec call:
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

Comment: I do have error reporting set. I updated my post to show the exact error I see.

Comment: interesting, so if you ignore the web server 404 then it returns the api data to you.  there must be a redirect in the application after the 404.  if you open the file directly in a browser like firefox or chrome and persist the network traffic, you may be able to uncover what happens after the 404 to allow you to get the data.

Comment: can you point us to an online location to review the code of the library that is running the api or is this a personally built api?

Comment: I use postman to submit http test requests and the api responds just fine. It seems to only be a problem when called directly from php and only in this one instance. I have dozens of other identical php POST calls to other files that work just fine as well. Unfortunately the api is proprietary so it would not be possible to link it.

Comment: I am curious if you also get the 404 from curl.  If you're curious enough to try it, it may lead to more answers.

Comment: Here are the first few lines from curl: [url] => http://localhost/api/v1/user/john/photos
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 196
    [request_size] => 249

Comment: Also want to note that calling the api with curl instead of file_get_contents worked and I could reach the api, but as you see I'm still getting a 404 even with curl.

Comment: check my update in my answer - let's look at the request/response headers in complete

Comment: Added the entire curl output.

Comment: i have to confess i expected to see redirection. as there is none, i'm baffled at this point. if it were me i would fool around with other paths (by creating other paths) and also other routes (perhaps it is a routing issue).

Comment: I'm out of ideas as well. I've tried everything I can think of. I guess I'll just have to ignore errors so I can at least debug the api and progress.